# Angular 2 Tabs retain after Refresh

Tags: angular, tabs, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I worked on tabs function its working fine but I want retain the selected tab active on page refresh.

```
<tabs>
  <tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'">Tab 1 Content</tab>
  <tab tabTitle="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</tab>
</tabs>
```

src/tabs.ts

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Tab } from './tab';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabs',
  template:`
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active">
        <a href="#">{{tab.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class Tabs implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChildren(Tab) tabs: QueryList<Tab>;

  // contentChildren are set
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // get all active tabs
    let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab)=>tab.active);

    // if there is no active tab set, activate the first
    if(activeTabs.length === 0) {
      this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    } 
  }

  selectTab(tab: Tab){
    // deactivate all tabs
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);

    // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
    tab.active = true;
  }

}
```

src/tab.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  styles: [`
    .pane{
      padding: 1em;
    }
  `],
  template: `
    <div [hidden]="!active" class="pane">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Tab {
  @Input('tabTitle') title: string;
  @Input() active = false;
}
```

This is a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ctzfDxkGDWvnetWVRfwI?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to store in a storage the selected tab index during `selectTab` , and check this during initialization `ngAfterContentInit`.
For this example, we'll use localStorage.

in src/tabs.ts

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    // get all active tabs
    let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab)=>tab.active);
    //get the active tab from storage,
    //if there are no stored, first tab is selected
    let selectedIndex: number =  parseInt(localStorage.getItem('selectedTabIndex'))  || 0;
    this.selectTab(this.tabs.toArray()[selectedIndex]);

}

selectTab(tab: Tab){
    // deactivate all tabs
    this.tabs.toArray().forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    //store selected tab index in localStorage
    let selectedIndex: number = this.tabs.toArray().indexOf(tab);
    localStorage.setItem('selectedTabIndex',selectedIndex);
    // activate the tab the user has clicked on.
    tab.active = true;
}
```

working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZkcBulnpqYcxjtQgXuG?p=preview

Comment: Facing one issue while implement with my actual project 
for selectedIndex 
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: I tried to add type  selectedIndex : any; but not working

Comment: For sure, because localstorage is  may be returning a string, try with parseInt() or +var, I updatet my answer

Comment: @Deepak don't need to save as JSON.stringify it's a number, a number.toString() may help but it's not needed . the error you have is by getting the value not by assigning :)  so just `let selectedIndex: number =  parseInt(localStorage.getItem('selectedTabIndex'))  || 0;`  the parseInt is the key

Comment: ok fine anyway its work for my requirement thanks for your quick support.